# Is there a web based IIS7 administration interface?

Tags: iis-7

Is there an app that allows for web based IIS administration?

Answer (score 1):

I have heard of http://www.awesomeideas.net/page/IIS7-Mobile-Admin.aspx but never used it myself.

Comment: I saw that, but it's a dinky little phone interface.